# Inconsistent behaviour of CDate()

Tags: vba, excel

Regional settings in Windows are `MM/DD/YYYY`

Now look at these two lines, and the change in the MONTH:

```
Sub DateBug()
    Debug.Print Format(CDate("11/4/1999"), "MMMM D, YYYY")
    Debug.Print Format(CDate("30/4/1999"), "MMMM D, YYYY")
End Sub
```

OUTPUT:

```
November 4, 1999
April 30, 1999
```

Great, huh? What is going on?

In the 2nd line, I want an **error**, not "guessing".

Is this a bug? Any idea how this can be circumvented ?

Same in Excel 2007, 2010, 2013

Comment: And `CDate("99/4/7")`delivers "April 7, 1999"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, its a "feature"

[image]

*CDate()* will interpret the string according to fixed rules.  If the date is valid as m/d/y, that will be returned.  If the date is not valid as m/d/y, but is valid as d/m/y, then that will be returned.  If the date is not valid as either m/d/y or d/m/y, then an error will be returned.

```
Sub dural()
    Dim st As String
    st = CStr(CDate("12/4/2012")) & vbCrLf & CStr(CDate("13/4/2012"))
    MsgBox st
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh yes, it's really a great feature, is has actually "spiced up" a report. BTW: `CDate("99/4/7")`delivers "April 7, 1999"

Comment: well yes, in the documentation it says "Any valid representation of a date and time." - which is a very vague "definiton" of the input parameter !

Comment: @StackWorm  Sadly, the year cannot be in the **second** position ........ *CDate("4/99/7")* will fail !!

Comment: Haha yes! In fact, there are 6 possible combinations to combine Year/Month/Day, which ones do work ?

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug.  VB will convert strings to date literals using the default regional settings, if it can.  Which it did in the first date.  But on the second date, that would have given an invalid date, so it tried DD/MM/YYYY and that worked.  Solution, put use date literals instead of strings.  Put # signs around both date literals (ex: '#4/30/1999#') to ignore regional setting and force use of the MM/DD/YYYY format.  '#30/4/1999#' would have given you the error you want.  This will make your code independent of the regional setting of the computer - ie, it will work regardless.  Or else use DateTime(1999, 4, 30, 0, 0, 0).  Look here... [Date Data Type (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx)

In Excel, you would use the literal without the single quotes:

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = CDate(#4/30/1999#)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, # does not work: `CDate("#11/4/1999#")`: "incompatible types". I think, the "#" formatting works only in MS Access, not in Excel VBA. Actually, the program reads from a text file and create a report out of it, so the input needs to be parsed, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, missed the "Excel" tag you had.  In Excel VBA, you would use the literal without the single quotes.  I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah now I understand you. But in your solution, the date is a LITERAL; However, I need a STRING VARIABLE, because the date is actually read from a text file !

Comment: I thought that might be the case, in which case, you are up the creek, I think.  I do not think there is a way to turn a string into a date literal.  The real solution then is that whatever process generated that text file, it should have constrained the dates to a reasonable format, not just let the user enter whatever.  That having failed, you cannot expect CDate to do the repair work for you.  You will have to write the error checking yourself - break the date string up into parts, then convert that, maybe using DateSerial and that would give you an error if you try to put 30 for the month.